# Font Awesome error: "downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"style:normal weight:900 stretch:100 src index:1)

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I found this with html

**In Firefox** *(Errors)*

```
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" style:normal weight:900 stretch:100 src index:1) source: http://localhost/project/public/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2

downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" style:normal  weight:900 stretch:100 src index:2) source: http://localhost/project/public/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff

downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" style:normal weight:900 stretch:100 src index:3) source: http://localhost/project/public/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf

downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" style:normal weight:900 stretch:100 src index:1) source: http://localhost/project/public/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2

downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" style:normal weight:900 stretch:100 src index:2) source: http://localhost/project/public/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff

downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" style:normal weight:900 stretch:100 src index:3) source: http://localhost/project/public/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf
```

**In Chrome** *(warning)*

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost/project/public/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2

localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost/project/public/webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff

localhost/:1 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost/project/public/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf
```

in Firfox the icon is not displayed: `<i class="fas fa-bars" ></i>`, But it was shown in chrome

I tried to read answers to similar questions but, I did not understand

I used in my project:

```
fontawesome-free-5.14.0-web

   -> all.min.css file,
   -> webfonts folder

project
  |--public
       |-css
          -all.min.css
       |-js
       |-webfonts
       |-index.php
```

all.css / all.min.css *(webfonts directory)*

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
    /* ...*/
    src: url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot");
    src: url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded- opentype"), 

    url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff") format("woff"), 
    url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf") format("truetype"), 
    url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

   /* ...*/
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    /* ..*/
    src: url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot");
    src: url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
    url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff2") format("woff2"),  
    url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.woff") format("woff"),   
    url("../webfonts/fa- regular-400.ttf") format("truetype"),
    url("../webfonts/fa-regular-400.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }

/* ...*/ 
@font-face {
     font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    /* ...*/ 
    src: url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot");
    src: url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
    url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype"), 
    url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.svg#fontawesome") format("svg"); }
```

Comment: Have you checked the import link in all.min.css

Comment: yes, I do <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/all.min.css">

Comment: What I meant was inside the all.min.css check the url for the webfonts .woff and others
so to know if it is getting the font folders from your directory arrangement

Comment: I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

You get this error if you run out of memory when loading the fontfile or if there is something wrong with the layout (contents) of the fontfile. This is a protection against bad or malicious font files. It is probably possible to disable the sanitizer by setting the pref gfx.downloadable_fonts.sanitize to false in about:config but then you are no longer protected. Use at your own risk. Do not blame Mozilla if you are infected with malware.

[support.mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/913498)

Comment: I read this solution before, but I didn't understand

Comment: Try this answer to see if it helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695042/why-is-firefox-rejecting-ttf-fonts

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@import` instead of `@font-face`.

I had these same errors loading Google fonts, and solved it with:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost&display=swap');
```