# Url descriptor in font-family

Tags: html, css, font-face

Segments:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'RobotoLight';
src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot');
src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.svg#RobotoLight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

From [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154219/when-using-css-font-face-in-what-order-do-browsers-use-the-different-types), I learn its value is a prioritized by `comma-separated` list. Then, from [the post](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-css3-font-face-design/), I learned such url's layout is for compatibility of browsers(especially ie9).

However, I still don't know the priority of `semicolon`, so I am confused, why I have never seen such layout below? is it correct version?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'RobotoLight';
src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot') format('eot'),
src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.svg#RobotoLight') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal; }
```

Comment: FYI: The `..` in `../font/jura-demibold.eot` won't mean anything if used in a web request. That's a file system shortcut to move up one directory, but URLs don't work like file systems.

Comment: @JDB Ok, I just extract the segments from one website.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the src property is a prioritized list, so each browser will use the first font in the list that is in a format it supports.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#src-desc

Comment: Does the priority also make sense to semicolon list?

Comment: Semicolon is just to work around a bug in IE8 and older. They have a bug in their parsers for the src attribute which causes them to 404 if more than 1 font source is in the css. You could add anything instead of ?#iefix as long as you use a question mark first

Answer (score 0):

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'RobotoLight';
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot') format('eot');
src: url('../font/jura-demibold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../font/jura-demibold.svg#RobotoLight') format('svg');
 }
```

That is how I would do it and do it on production sites. The only change is adding a semi-colon at the end of your first `src` attribute.

Comment: What I wonder to know is why the second version is not correct?

Comment: It might be because you need to place the a semi-colon at the end of line 3 in your second version.